# Unable to see wireless network

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I have HP 530 laptop, I installed Ubuntu 12.10 OS. I am unable to see/enable wireless network. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify if you have the wireless access and your internet is running fine with no network icon at top panel.

Well, if your network is at fault,

Open the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> .

Type `rfkill list` in the terminal.

You should get a similar result with wireless lan 'yes' for soft-blocked.

```
saket@saket:~$ rfkill list

0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

You can fix this by typing the following code in terminal and rebooting the laptop.

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

If the internet access is fine and the networking icon is missing, type the following lines into the terminal and the panel should be working fine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo reboot
```